# Maven java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, xml, maven, visual-studio-code

I'm new to java and I created my project using maven. I have a `pom.xml` file that  looks like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.swingy.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>swingy</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>swingy</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
      <version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.36</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

and my main java program looks roughly/simply like this

```java
package com.swingy.app;

import java.sql.*;

public class App {
    static Connection conn = null;
    static PreparedStatement pStatement = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        makeJDBCConnection();

    }

    private static void makeJDBCConnection() {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/", "root", "Pass");
            if (conn != null) {
                System.out.println("Connection Successful! Enjoy. Now it's time to push data");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("MySQL Connection Failed!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

This compiles correctly with `mvn clean package` then when I try to run with `java -jar target/swingy-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` I get this error

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

I've looked everywhere for the answer and most articles suggest I `"add the .jar file"` to my classpath but I don't know what this might mean because everything I've tried like downloading the `.jar` file to the project path, still nothing. I'm using vscode and my this is my project tree structure

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   └── java
│   │       └── com
│   │           └── swingy
│   │               ├── app
│   │               │   ├── App.java
│   │               │   └── Main.java
│   │               ├── controls
│   │               ├── models
│   │               │   └── Player.java
│   │               └── views
│   │                   └── Colors.java
│   └── test
│       └── java
│           └── com
│               └── swingy
│                   └── app
│                       └── AppTest.java
└── target
    ├── classes
    ...
```

Comment: Make up your mind. Your code says MySQL but your pom.xml says Oracle OJDBC.

Comment: @user207421 This  is all based on tutorials and the error suggests the problem is with ojdbc driver missing so i figured it might be dependant on it, remember I'm new to this.

Comment: The error suggests that the *MySQL* driver is missing.

Comment: You need to learn and understand how the classpath works, because this is one of the things that most new programmers run into having a problem with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add your dependencies in your final jar which can be done by maven using the following plugin:

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <mainClass>com.swingy.app.App</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

To run your project, you can use the following command:

```
java -jar target/swingy-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

I hope it works for you :)

Comment: could you let me know why you have downgraded my answer, please?

Comment: Thank you it works. I didn't downvote your answer, someone else did

Comment: any way, I'm glad I was able to help :)